# Replace an electric baseboard heater safely?

Tags: electrical, wiring, 240v, baseboard

Basement apt of a triplex with the original 1960's wiring  on a 15 watt fuse.

**Question:**
How do I replace my old double pole 240v electric baseboard heater safely?

Comment: How many watts is the heater? Why are you seeking to replace it? Are you having trouble shutting the power off? Can you post photos of the fuses (there should be two) for this heater, for that matter?

Comment: I think you mean a 15 amp fuse. A true fuse? or double pole circuit breaker?  Be very careful here. If a double pole circuit breaker, just turn it off and you should be fine, but always double check with a meter.   DO NOT COUNT on turning down the thermostat to cut off power to the baseboard. Many line voltage Tstats only cut one leg of the 240v circuit, leaving the other leg hot.

Comment: If you are renting this apartment, you are not allowed to replace a baseboard heater yourself.

Comment: In either direction -- *neither* landlords *nor* tenants can work on a rental unit - licensed electricians only!!!  However, are you 100% sure it's not the thermostat?  Many local authorities will allow mortals to swap light switches, receps and fixtures, and those would likely allow a thermostat also.